# AuCTeX Preview "Finds No Preview Images"

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am currently trying to set up AuCTeX in emacs, but I'm encountering difficulty in getting the preview feature to work. For reference, I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, GNU Emacs 24.3.1, AuCTeX 11.87.7 (installed via the package manager), and GhostScript v8.71 32-bit (because I saw from previous questions that later versions had some bugs with the preview feature).

I have installed the relevant dlls to allow for PNG display, but now I am getting an error that:

> Preview-LaTeX exited as expected with code 1 at Sun Oct  5 01:21:33
>   LaTeX: LaTeX found no preview images

This is from the default circ.tex file included as a test, and Ghostscript is indeed running, and the images are definitely being rendered and being saved in either a pdf (when I try it in pdftex mode) or a dvi (when I try it with pdftex mode turned off), but they aren't showing up in the buffer, nor does it seem like emacs even recognizes that the files were created. I've browsed through multiple help questions regarding this issue, but I haven't found a solution that works for me. Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if you require any additional information.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Can you view a *.png file in a buffer all by itself -- e.g., just open it like you would any other file and display it as an image?  This is a test without using AUCTeX just to see if the *.png images can be displayed properly by Emacs.

Comment: what version of the dll files do you have? I have `libpng16-16.dll` and `zlib1.dll` which I have recently downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/). After a couple of errors, I finally got the preview-latex feature to work. (I've recently had a similar [problem](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16426/how-to-configure-latest-32-bit-emacs-auctex-in-windows-7))